# Splitting an alphanumeric string like "3a" or "32ab" in mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, alphanumeric

I would like to split an alphanumeric string like 3a into "3" and "a".  Please help if any one has an idea.  I can't use the $split in mongodb aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is efficient, but this answer may give you a solution.
Since we can't use regex in `$split`,

1. First stage - divide the sentence into words and store in `char[]`
2. Flat the `char[]` using `$unwind`
3. Categorize all string into `strings[]` and all numbers into `numbers[]` using `$facet`. Here we use `$match` with `regex`
4. Then combined as what you need.

Assume this is your string.

```
{
  char:"32ab"
}
```

The mongo script might be,

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields: {
  'char': {
    $map: {
      input: {
        $range: [
          0,
          {
            $strLenCP: '$char'
          }
        ]
      },
      'in': {
        $substrCP: [
          '$char',
          '$$this',
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: '$char',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
}}, {$facet: {
  strings: [
    {
      $match: {
        'char': RegExp('^[A-Za-z]+$')
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        arr: {
          $push: '$char'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        combined: {
          $reduce: {
            input: '$arr',
            initialValue: '',
            'in': {
              $concat: [

                                '$$value',
                '$$this'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  numbers: [
    {
      $match: {
        'char': {
          $not: RegExp('^[A-Za-z]+$')
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        arr: {
          $push: '$char'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        combined: {
          $reduce: {
            input: '$arr',
            initialValue: '',
            'in': {
              $concat: [
               '$$value',
                '$$this'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}}, {$project: {
  string: {
    $arrayElemAt: [
      {
        $ifNull: [
          '$strings.combined',
          ''
        ]
      },
      0
    ]
  },
  number: {
    $toInt:{
    $arrayElemAt: [
      {
        $ifNull: [
          '$numbers.combined',
          ''
        ]
      },
      0
    ]
  }
  }
}}])
```

And the output is

```
{
   string : "ab",
   numbers: 32
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use your addFields to split the string.  And that's all I needed.  {$addFields: {
  'char': {
    $map: {
      input: {
        $range: [
          0,
          {
            $strLenCP: '$char'
          }
        ]
      },
      'in': {
        $substrCP: [
          '$char',
          '$$this',
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}}

Comment: @Netit My bad, my answer was unaccepted. May I know what is the reason, so I will try to improve!!

Comment: I have a field sometimes it has numbers only and sometimes it has a string of alphanumeric values  like 12b or 3a or 23b etc.  I want to test the field to see if it has a number then I will just return that number.  But if after testing it, it has an alphanumeric value I would like to split the letters and the numbers.  I hope that explanation is clearer.   Many thanks.

Comment: My aggregation gives you as you expected either 'string' or 'number' or 'both''. What is wrong with it

Comment: I am not sure if you have tested your query but it does not for me at least.  $strLenCP:  requires a string argument.